# How do I convert it to work in multiprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, opencv, multiprocessing

I am working on a robot and want to do all processing on my raspberry pi. I started looking into multithreading which looked promising but as I am trying to do more operation the rpi is throttling.

This is the class which takes the coordinates and tell whether to move up down or right left.

I have added which variables are being changed from my main.py file

Is it possible to get this working in different CPU or should I change my approach ?

```
Controller.py
from dataPointObject.dataPointObjectClass import *
import threading


class Drive:

    def __init__(self, frameInfo=FrameInfo()):
        self.facePoint = FacePoint() // changing from main.py
        self.obstaclePoint = ObstaclePoint() // changing from main.py
        self.frameInfo = frameInfo
        self.isDetected = False // changing from main.py
        self.stopped = False // changing from main.py

    def start(self):
        print('Started')
        threading.Thread(name='Drive', target=self.drive).start()
        threading.Thread(name='AdjustCamera', target=self.adjustCamera).start()
        return self

    def drive(self):
        while not self.stopped:
            while self.isDetected:
                if self.facePoint.x+self.facePoint.w > self.frameInfo.frameWidthLimitR:  # Right Screen Margin
                    print('LEFT')
                elif self.facePoint.x < self.frameInfo.frameWidthLimitL:  # Left Screen Margin
                    print('RIGHT')

    def adjustCamera(self):
        while not self.stopped:
            while self.isDetected:
                if self.facePoint.y < self.frameInfo.frameHeightLimitT:  # Top Screen Margin
                    print('DOWN')
                elif self.facePoint.y + self.facePoint.h > self.frameInfo.frameHeightLimitB:  # Bottom Screen Margin
                    print('UP')

    def stop(self):
        self.isDetected = False
        self.stopped = True

    def faceDetected(self , isDetected = False):
        self.isDetected = isDetected

    def setFacePoint(self,facePoint):
        self.facePoint = facePoint
```

This is the function which i am calling to start processing.
VideoGet and VideoShow are working on different thread

```
def start(source=0):

    video_getter = VideoGet(source).start()
    video_shower = VideoShow(video_getter.frame , video_getter.frameInfo).start()
    drive = Drive(frameInfo = video_getter.frameInfo).start()
    while True:
        drive.faceDetected(video_shower.facePoint != FacePoint())
        drive.setFacePoint(video_shower.facePoint)
        if video_getter.stopped or video_shower.stopped:
            video_shower.stop()
            video_getter.stop()
            drive.stop()
            break

        frame = video_getter.frame
        video_shower.frame = frame
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the %CPU by top command in command line. if it is around 100% then the program is using only single core. Python threading is limited by GIL, to use all available cpu, we must use multiprocessing instead of multithreading.

Or, if the case is that rpi is throttling because of high temperature then you may put appropriate milliseconds time sleep (like time.sleep(0.02) ) in while roop. this is very simple solution and it works.